# MySQL Python - before you commit, where is the update info stored?

Tags: python, mysql

This is a question mostly for my understanding of how the system works. I am using `mysql.connector` to update my databse from Python.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(
    user='testdb', 
    password='testdb',
    database='testdb',
    host='127.0.0.1',
)
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute( "UPDATE testdb SET descr='konijn' WHERE number=14549")

mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

Before running `mariadb_connection.commit()`, the update is not offical and I would not see the updated data in my database. My question is: after running `cursor.execute` and before running `mariadb_connection.commit()`, where is the information about the update stored? Is it still stored in the local machine's RAM or is it already somewhere in the MySQL databse, but not official shown yet until `commit` is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes are stored in an in-progress transaction in the MariaDB database server.

`db.commit()` corresponds to the [`COMMIT` SQL statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/commit/).